# Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code

```
authComplete$.subscribe(([user, loggedIn]) => {
```

obviously this is just a incomplete code snippit of the line that the error is being caused on. The error being

`Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

I have no idea how to fix this. Or what this even means

Here is the full code and my research so far

```
private handleAuthCallback() {
    // Call when app reloads after user logs in with Auth0
    const params = window.location.search;
    if (params.includes('code=') && params.includes('state=')) {
      let targetRoute: string; // Path to redirect to after login processsed
      const authComplete$ = this.handleRedirectCallback$.pipe(
        // Have client, now call method to handle auth callback redirect
        tap(cbRes => {
          // Get and set target redirect route from callback results
          targetRoute = cbRes.appState && cbRes.appState.target ? cbRes.appState.target : '/';
        }),
        concatMap(() => {
          // Redirect callback complete; get user and login status
          return combineLatest([
            this.getUser$(),
            this.isAuthenticated$
          ]);
        })
      );
      // Subscribe to authentication completion observable
      // Response will be an array of user and login status
      authComplete$.subscribe(([user, loggedIn]) => {     // <-- line error is on
        // Redirect to target route after callback processing
        this.router.navigate([targetRoute]);
      });
    }
  }
```

this is in dealing with the auth0 angular intergration example which can be located here
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

my research so far is with this website:

https://www.geekabyte.io/2019/06/typing-iterables-and-iterators-with.html

but to be honest after reading it a few times im even more confused.

I did see that I may need to change some settings in my angular app to which I did in my tsconfig.json file

```
"lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom",
      "es5", "es6", "dom.iterable"
    ]
```

help would be appreciated

Comment: can you try creating a demo to produce the issue  using https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: no as this is a compile time failure

Answer (score 1):

so I'm not sure if this is the solution but I removed the user and logged in

```
authComplete$.subscribe(([user, loggedIn]) => {
```

is now:

```
authComplete$.subscribe() => {
```

I have to continue setting up my auth scheme to see if the code will work or break. Once I have my answer I will further detail this answer.

However as far as code compiling removing the array did work.